# Do monsters spawned from statues drop monster banners?

Tags: terraria

I've been wondering if monsters spawned from statues drop the monster banners in the 1.2 update. If I can recall I remember farming a Slime Statue and I eventually got a slime banner, however I have tried it on the other statues yet I have had no success. Am I just unlucky or only certain monsters spawned from the statues can drop the monster banners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have first hand experience, but the wiki page indicates that you can get banners.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Statues

Comment: Thanks for the verification, ill try farming other statues as well. Also the wiki seems to show that the monsters spawned from the statues also drop other loot as well.

Comment: @Mr.Snipe yup, it looks like they drop the vanity/minor items. Its the shame that the mimic statues cant drop the good accessories :x

Comment: In my opinion that would be bad if mimics dropped all their loot, it would break the game to a certain point in money since you could easily profit from selling their drops. Just imagine having a lot of valuable coins combined with a Coin Gun, you would just be overpowered. You could also do other things with that sort of money such as reforging powerful enchantments/perks for your weapons and accessories or buying tons of supplies from the NPCs.

Comment: @Mr.Snipe I completely agree. At the moment, I am just a little tired of getting dupe accessories instead of the ones I want each time I kill one.